# Чем обусификацировали этот файл?

Tags: php

Вот его содежимое:

```
<?php // This file is protected by copyright law and provided under license. Reverse engineering of this file is strictly prohibited.
$OOO0O0O00=__FILE__;$O00O00O00=__LINE__;$OO00O0000=88;eval((base64_decode('JE8wMDBPME8wMD1mb3BlbigkT09PME8wTzAwLCdyYicpO3doaWxlKC0tJE8wME8wME8wMClmZ2V0cygkTzAwME8wTzAwLDEwMjQpO2ZnZXRzKCRPMDAwTzBPMDAsNDA5Nik7JE9PMDBPMDBPMD0oYmFzZTY0X2RlY29kZShzdHJ0cihmcmVhZCgkTzAwME8wTzAwLDM3MiksJ0VudGVyeW91d2toUkhZS05XT1VUQWFCYkNjRGRGZkdnSWlKakxsTW1QcFFxU3NWdlh4WnowMTIzNDU2Nzg5Ky89JywnQUJDREVGR0hJSktMTU5PUFFSU1RVVldYWVphYmNkZWZnaGlqa2xtbm9wcXJzdHV2d3h5ejAxMjM0NTY3ODkrLycpKSk7ZXZhbCgkT08wME8wME8wKTs=')));return;?>
    kr9NHenNHenNHe1lFMamb3klFoxiC2APk19gOLlHOa9gkZXJkZwVkr9NTznNHr8XHt4JkZwShokiF2A2Yy9LcBYvcoAPF3OZfuwPcmklCBWPkr8XHenNHr8XHtXLT08XHr8XHeEXhUXmOB50cbk5d3a3D2iUUylRTlfNaaOnCAkJW2YrcrcMO2fkDApQToxYdanXAbyTF1c2BuiDGjExHjH0YTC3KeLqRz0mRtfnWLYrOAcuUrlhU0xYTL9WAakTayaBa1icBMyJC2OlcMfPDBpqdo1Vd3nxFmY0fbc3Gul6HerZHzW1YjF4KUSvkZLphUL7cMYSd3YlhtONHeEXTznNHeEpK2a2CBXPkr9NHenNHenNHtL7tJEIwtnZcby1Dbklb29VC2APwMilCBOlFJ5XDuEJhTShwtEIwuklFbapFMagd25jcUIJcM9vfoaZRmnPFtwpKXP=
```

2 файл parse.php:

```
<?php /* This file is protected by copyright law and provided under license. Reverse engineering of this file is strictly prohibited. */$OOO000000=urldecode('%66%67%36%73%62%65%68%70%72%61%34%63%6f%5f%74%6e%64');$GLOBALS['OOO0000O0']=$OOO000000{4}.$OOO000000{9}.$OOO000000{3}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{2}.$OOO000000{10}.$OOO000000{13}.$OOO000000{16};$GLOBALS['OOO0000O0'].=$GLOBALS['OOO0000O0']{3}.$OOO000000{11}.$OOO000000{12}.$GLOBALS['OOO0000O0']{7}.$OOO000000{5};$GLOBALS['OOO000O00']=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{12}.$OOO000000{7}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{15};$GLOBALS['O0O000O00']=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{1}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{14};$GLOBALS['O0O000O00']=$O0O000O00.$OOO000000{3};$GLOBALS['O0O00OO00']=$OOO000000{0}.$OOO000000{8}.$OOO000000{5}.$OOO000000{9}.$OOO000000{16};$GLOBALS['OOO00000O']=$OOO000000{3}.$OOO000000{14}.$OOO000000{8}.$OOO000000{14}.$OOO000000{8};$OOO0O0O00=__FILE__;$OO00O0000=0x41b0;eval($GLOBALS['OOO0000O0']('JE8wMDBPME8wMD0kR0xPQkFMU1snT09PMDAwTzAwJ10oJE9PTzBPME8wMCwncmInKTskR0xPQkFMU1snTzBPMDBPTzAwJ10oJE8wMDBPME8wMCwweDU3Zik7JE9PMDBPMDBPMD0kR0xPQkFMU1snT09PMDAwME8wJ10oJEdMT0JBTFNbJ09PTzAwMDAwTyddKCRHTE9CQUxTWydPME8wME9PMDAnXSgkTzAwME8wTzAwLDB4MWE4KSwnbG9ja2V5WUVLQ09MQWFCYkRkRmZHZ0hoSWlKak1tTm5QcFFxUnJTc1R0VXVWdld3WHhaejAxMjM0NTY3ODkrLz0nLCdBQkNERUZHSElKS0xNTk9QUVJTVFVWV1hZWmFiY2RlZmdoaWprbG1ub3BxcnN0dXZ3eHl6MDEyMzQ1Njc4OSsvJykpO2V2YWwoJE9PMDBPMDBPMCk7'));return;?>IxeCe9bAkobAkobAk1zmECnMSgXjYyqiFPsh19YFGxyh18sLcKsKQ4Rf09bAe8XfzlXLQKsKQXRd0xbDRyAG1Vsf09bAklXAe8XC10TCemAf0CofyajC09bfzlXAklXfZmmOcdEfe9cDGxfHZmbAe8XAe9bAklshFPRfzlXAe8XfzlXLcdbfzlXfzlXAkltLcmVj2auihridGvkf0xoIGCQdYdYiRmsFYpCJGtUfH1BjroXGhyFMrazgEdgmgi2g3mINyt6AkeZAzD1aqM4BFVwbFMVC0ycD0dydRmKFGtLfe1Bf1odGraGggihHyrJIHCqiYgSi2ptJSvVjH5wMEyZM3d1msm4NhTXAfKzakG2azP5OZ8sOFRtB2iqjY9ziFPRfzlXAe8XfzlXOfvrmSyVOcdbfzlXfzlXfzltBX==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_]TK|VuE{SMIJ\
```

Comment: кто за то что бы создать сервис по декодированию php lockit?

Comment: @good18 для уже прошаренных людей он не нужен особо, а другим будет повод поучиться. Думаю, это лишнее.

Answer (score 1):

Обфускатор не помню, вроде как **php lockit**, но так-то всё просто, вместо `eval` подставляете `echo`, пока не получите читаемый текст.

Ваш код содержит:

```
require_once("header.php");
require_once("footer.php");
```

И второй файл, он был чуть сложнее зашифрован: http://pastebin.com/czvkKV46

Comment: @good18 ну я ж написал, вместо eval подставляете echо и немного подумываете, что будет, если чуть изменить порядок строк.

Answer (score 1):

Вот [тред](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?bid=18&tid=919214&pg=1), в котором обсуждается алгоритм дешифровки подобного кода ([пост](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualutils.aspx?action=gotomsg&tid=919214&msg=12117123) с описанием алгоритма). Вот [тулза](http://ottodestruct.com/decoder2.php), которая, собственно, производит декодирование.

Comment: данная тулза подходит только для 1 файла

Comment: В [этом][1] треде алгоритм декодирования для второго файла.

  [1]: http://board.deioncube.in/showthread.php?tid=1306

Comment: @good18 вот второй файл, там просто адовый говнокод: http://pastebin.com/czvkKV46

Comment: я и сам его расшифровал только их не 1-2 их около 100, вот пишу программку для расшифровки

Comment: @klopp я бы сказал, 50%/50% что обфусцировали говнокод. В своё время использовал ioncube. Во-первых боязнь, что каким-то образом сольют код и заюзают его в другом месте (а по логам это было отчетливо видно, долбили как сам проект, так и сам сервер), либо сольют код и будут использовать уязвимости "нулевого дня".

Answer (score 0):

Чем ОБФУСЦИРОВАЛИ файл я не знаю. Но есть подозрение, что вам не это нужно. Вы хотите расшифровать

> JE8wMDBPME8wMD1mb3BlbigkT09PME8wTzAwLCdyYicpO3doaWxlKC0tJE8wME8wME8wMClmZ2V0cygkTzAwME8wTzAwLDEwMjQpO2ZnZXRzKCRPMDAwTzBPMDAsNDA5Nik7JE9PMDBPMDBPMD0oYmFzZTY0X2RlY29kZShzdHJ0cihmcmVhZCgkTzAwME8wTzAwLDM3MiksJ0VudGVyeW91d2toUkhZS05XT1VUQWFCYkNjRGRGZkdnSWlKakxsTW1QcFFxU3NWdlh4WnowMTIzNDU2Nzg5Ky89JywnQUJDREVGR0hJSktMTU5PUFFSU1RVVldYWVphYmNkZWZnaGlqa2xtbm9wcXJzdHV2d3h5ejAxMjM0NTY3ODkrLycpKSk7ZXZhbCgkT08wME8wME8wKTs

Для этого просто воспользуйтесь функцией base64_decode()

```
<?php
print base64_decode('JE8wMDBPME8wMD1mb3BlbigkT09PME8wTzAwLCdyYicpO3doaWxlKC0tJE8wME8wME8wMClmZ2V0cygkTzAwME8wTzAwLDEwMjQpO2ZnZXRzKCRPMDAwTzBPMDAsNDA5Nik7JE9PMDBPMDBPMD0oYmFzZTY0X2RlY29kZShzdHJ0cihmcmVhZCgkTzAwME8wTzAwLDM3MiksJ0VudGVyeW91d2toUkhZS05XT1VUQWFCYkNjRGRGZkdnSWlKakxsTW1QcFFxU3NWdlh4WnowMTIzNDU2Nzg5Ky89JywnQUJDREVGR0hJSktMTU5PUFFSU1RVVldYWVphYmNkZWZnaGlqa2xtbm9wcXJzdHV2d3h5ejAxMjM0NTY3ODkrLycpKSk7ZXZhbCgkT08wME8wME8wKTs');
?>
```

Comment: там не все так просто